# How to verify today date with last CoreData entry

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a **CoreData** attributes that 2 (value, date). When I click on a **UIButton**, it added an entry corresponding to the value of the **UIButton**.

I will wish to limit the addition of entry to a daily. Basically, *I will wish to check the current date and the date of the last entry. If it's value are identical, this is not added*.

My Function

```
func data(sender: UIButton) {

    // Date Format

    let date = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY/MM/dd"
    let dateFormat = formatter.stringFromDate(date)


    // Load Entity

    let AppDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let theContext : NSManagedObjectContext = AppDel.managedObjectContext
    let theEnt = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Mood", inManagedObjectContext: theContext)


    // Create Item

    let newItem = Mood(entity: theEnt!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: theContext)
    newItem.mood = String(sender.tag)
    newItem.date = dateFormat

    // Save Item

    do {

        try theContext.save()

    } catch _ {

    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fetch the `Mood` objects, sorted by `date` in descending order, the first item returned will be the last entry.  You can set the `fetchLimit` to 1 to avoid loading more objects than are necessary.  You can then test to see whether the date attribute matches, and handle accordingly:

```
func data(sender: UIButton) {
    // Date Format
    let date = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY/MM/dd"
    let dateFormat = formatter.stringFromDate(date)    
    // Get context and entity details    
    let AppDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let theContext : NSManagedObjectContext = AppDel.managedObjectContext
    let theEnt = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Mood", inManagedObjectContext: theContext)
    // Fetch the latest entry
    let fetch = NSFetchRequest()
    fetch.entity = theEnt!
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending:false)
    fetch.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    fetch.fetchLimit = 1
    let results = try! theContext.executeFetchRequest(fetch) as! [Mood]
    // NB should do proper try/catch error checking
    // Check for existing entry
    if (results.count > 0) {
        // Check whether date matches
        if (results[0].date != dateFormat) {
            let newItem = Mood(entity: theEnt!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: theContext)
            newItem.mood = String(sender.tag)
            newItem.date = dateFormat
        }
    } else { // No entries yet, I assume you want to add one...
        let newItem = Mood(entity: theEnt!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: theContext)
        newItem.mood = String(sender.tag)
        newItem.date = dateFormat
    }
    // Save Item    
    do {
        try theContext.save()
    } catch _ {    
    }
}
```

Note that (given your code `newItem.date = dateFormat`) I am assuming the `date` attribute is a string which you set using the same format ("YYYY/MM/dd").  This strips out the time information and so avoids the need for the date comparisons, but also has the advantage that a string sort is equivalent to a date sort (perhaps you chose that format for that reason).  If `date` is in fact a Date attribute, the sort will still work but you will need to use a date comparison.

Comment: It's the good function (Yes, my date is a String). But I have a problem with "results[0].date != dateFormat". I have an error: "fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type". But it's the good index for results ?

Comment: That implies that the items returned by the fetch are not of class Mood.  Check that the class is set in the data model editor.

Comment: That's works perfectly. So, my entity "Mood" as a class "Mood", funny. Bit I add the Module "Current Product Module", otherwise it does not work.

Comment: @pbasdf Any chance to you could do a version or swift 5 I'm struggling with something very similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59547446/check-todays-date-against-last-coredata-entry?noredirect=1#comment105270997_59547446)

Answer (score 2):

I use an `NSDate` extension for this.

```
extension NSDate {
    class func areDatesSameDay(dateOne:NSDate,dateTwo:NSDate) -> Bool {
        let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let flags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Day, .Month, .Year]
        let compOne: NSDateComponents = calender.components(flags, fromDate: dateOne)
        let compTwo: NSDateComponents = calender.components(flags, fromDate: dateTwo);
        return (compOne.day == compTwo.day && compOne.month == compTwo.month && compOne.year == compTwo.year);
    }
}
```

Usage is like this.

```
if NSDate.areDatesSameDay(dateOne, dateTwo: dateTwo) {
    // Dates are same day
} else {
    // Dates are not the same day
}
```

---

**@Tom Harrington** Has just pointed out that you can use the `NSCalendar` methods to do this more simply

```
let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
if calender.isDate(dateOne, inSameDayAsDate: dateTwo) {
    // Dates are same day
}
```

So we can make my lovely extension even simpler...

```
extension NSDate {
    func isSameDayAs(date:NSDate) -> Bool {
        let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        return calender.isDate(self, inSameDayAsDate: date)
    }
}
```

Then use it like this.

```
if dateOne.isSameDayAs(dateTwo) {
    // Dates are same day
} else {
    // Dates are not the same day
}
```

And thats **Numberwang!**

Comment: Thank you, it's works. But it's a date comparator. I must also recover the last entry in my Entity, for comparison.

Comment: Beginning with iOS 8, you can use `isDate(_:inSameDayAsDate:)` to compare dates like this. It's an `NSCalendar` method.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'd not seen that! I will just add it to the answer.

Comment: @KevinPy Did you manage to recover the last entry in your Entity it in the end? Struggling with something similar.